# Insert converted varchar into datetime sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, insert

I need to insert a `varchar` in my table. The type in the table is a `datetime` so I need to convert it. I didn't think this would be to big of a problem however it keeps inserting `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` instead of the date I want. When I do a select with my converted date it does show me the correct date.

I'll show you the code:

```
INSERT INTO Item (CategoryId, [Date], Content, CreatedOn)
   SELECT 
       CategoryId, Convert(datetime, '28/11/2012', 103), Content, GetDate()
   FROM 
       Item i
   JOIN 
       Category c ON i.CategoryId = c.Id
   JOIN 
       Division d ON d.Id = c.DivisionId
   WHERE 
       Date = Convert(datetime, '31/03/2005', 103) 
       AND d.Id = '142aaddf-5b63-4d53-a331-8eba9b0556c4'
```

The where clause works perfectly and gives me the filtered items I need, all data is correctly inserted except for the converted date. The gives like I said 1900-...

If I just do the select so:

```
SELECT CategoryId, Convert(datetime, '28/11/2012', 103), Content, GetDate()
FROM Item i
JOIN Category c ON i.CategoryId = c.Id
JOIN Division d ON d.Id = c.DivisionId
WHERE Date = Convert(datetime, '31/03/2005', 103) AND d.Id = '142aaddf-5b63-4d53-a331-8eba9b0556c4'
```

I get the correct date being: `2012-11-28 00:00:00.000`. I have tried to use a different conversion like:

```
Convert(datetime, '20121128')
```

But that just gives the same problem. Anyone that sees what I'm doing wrong?

Thx

Comment: How come you are using the same table in the select and insert statements?

Comment: Might there be a trigger on the table?

Comment: You are inserting a constant string or field value?

Comment: What I am doing is actually calling this query from visual studio and giving the dates in dynamically. I pass the query as a string with the values entered. But at the moment I am just testing the query in sql server cause as long it doesn't work there it is useless to use it in my application. I am using the same table because I need to copy items from one date to another. So the item needs to be exactly the same just on 2 different days

Comment: Side note - when you're passing the values from visual studio (presumably from a .NET program in VS), you ought to be passing them as `DateTime`s anyway, not converting back and forth to strings.

Comment: Yes but I need to pass the whole query as a string including the dates already inside the string. So I have to have a string. Not the easiest way but it's how it has to be done

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you must use a string-based date format, you should pick one that is **safe** and works in every SQL Server instance, regardless of date format, language and regional settings.

That format is known as **ISO-8601** format and it's either

```
YYYYMMDD      (note: **NO** dashes!)
```

or

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSS
```

for a `DATETIME` column.

So instead of

```
Convert(datetime, '28/11/2012', 103)
```

you should use

```
CAST('20121128' AS DATETIME)
```

and then you should be fine.

If you're on SQL Server **2008** - you could also look into using `DATE` (instead of `DATETIME`) for cases when you only need the date (no time portion). That would be even easier than using `DATETIME` and having the time portion always be `00:00:00`

Comment: It still gives me the exact same thing. I used CAST('20121128' AS DATETIME) but the inserted date keeps 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000. I cannot use date because in the future the hours might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to throw out the fact that I found this SO Question (and many others like it) years later while trying to find the answer to my problem.

If you are troubleshooting this inside a stored procedure, the parameter of the stored procedure is where you need to modify. The programmer who created the code I'm troubleshooting had `@ddt CHAR(10)` and no modifications inside the stored procedure resolved the problem. I had to change the parameter to `@ddt smalldatetime`.